# How to serve static files in node.js after renaming them?

Tags: javascript, node.js, koa, node-static

I am creating a node.js app in which user can upload files and can download later.
I am storing file information (original file name that user uploaded, ...) in mongodb document and named that file same as mongodb document id. Now i want my user to be able to download that file with the original file name.

What i want to know is when a user sends a GET request on http://myapp.com/mongoDocument_Id
user gets a file named myOriginalfile.ext

I know about node-static and other modules but i can't rename them before sending file.

i am using koa.js framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a simple example using [`koa-file-server`](https://github.com/koajs/file-server):

```
var app   = require('koa')();
var route = require('koa-route');
var send  = require('koa-file-server')({ root : './static' }).send;

app.use(route.get('/:id', function *(id) {
  // TODO: perform lookup from id to filename here.

  // We'll use a hardcoded filename as an example.
  var filename = 'test.txt';

  // Set the looked-up filename as the download name.
  this.attachment(filename);

  // Send the file.
  yield send(this, id);
}));

app.listen(3012);
```

In short:

- the files are stored in `./static` using the MongoDB id as their filename
- a user requests http://myapp.com/123456
- you look up that ID in MongoDB to find out the original filename (in the example above, the filename is just hardcoded to `test.txt`)
- the file `./static/123456` is offered as a download using the original filename set in the `Content-Disposition` header (by using `this.attachment(filename)`), which will make the browser store it locally as `test.txt` instead of `123456`.

Comment: Thanks for your response i stuck in this for 6 hours.

Comment: Also this was my first question on stackoverflow so didn't expect such fast response. Thank you